# PHP / Mysql create a new array using values from an existing array, help?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I currently have the following array,

```
Array (1)
0 => Array (5)
  productid => 1
  qty => 1
  materialid => 12
```

and I have the following two queries which are

```
select name as productname, price from products where productid=1
```

and

```
select name from materials where materialid=12
```

I need to link these queries such that the array output is like this or similar:

```
Array (1)
0 => Array (5)
  productid => 1
  qty => 1
  materialid => 12
  productname => Toothbrush
  price => £3.00
```

This is basically to output the content on to a basket page. Note that the queries can not be joined as there isn't any joins on the two tables.

Thanks

Comment: [PHP's array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) can do this for you

Comment: The output array doesn't contain data from the second query, only productname and price from the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also query both tables at the same time:

```
select p.name as productname, m.name as materialname, p.price
    from products p, materials m
    where p.productid=1 and materialid=12
```

Comment: Hi All

I'd like to thank all of y'al for your responses, all of the solutions worked. I decided to go with David's solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run the first query, get the data as a keyed array. Run the second query, get the data as a keyed array as well. Then make a union of both arrays:

```
$data1 = query_data($sql1);
$data2 = query_data($sql2);
$result = array($data1 + $data2);
```

Will give you a result that is one array containing a single array with all values from `$data1` and `$data2`. Duplicate keys in `$data2` will not overwrite those from `$data1`. See [Array Operators in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

A similar function is [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) which does create one array out of two as well.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the data to populate the initial array? Does it always have a single value (if so you could use a cartesian join on a single query to avoid making 2 trips to the database). Why are the relations between the tables of data not described in the database?

Splicing the values from the array into the query, either as literals or as bound parameters is trivial. What is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

You can run query separately:

```
$res1 = mysql_query(Qry1); 
$res2 = mysql_query(Qry2);

$data1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
$data2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);

$res = array_merge_recursive($data1, $data2);
```